# Storing the lat long information of a moving object in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am writing a software that tracks a large number of devices about 30k. (Like Uber but the location information originates from different kind of GPS devices)

1. I get the location information of the devices every 5 second
2. Now I need to keep all the information in database such that it can be used for tracking any device or finding devices near you.

Here is what I have planned:

1. I have a Table in Dynamo db called Livetrack that keeps the latest location information of each device
2. Data contains deviceid, tiestamp, latitude, longitude

How should I design the DynamoDb table such that it can cater 30000 writes / 60000 reads every 5 seconds

- What should be my read and write capacity Units.
- I am going to use aws cloud DynamoDB once development gets completed
- Shall I not use DynamoTable and use caching like redis?

In local dynamodb installation, If i am not able to write 6 devices data every 5 second and read on device data simultaneously

My Livetrack data is created as:

```js
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")


table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='LocationOne',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'deviceid',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        }
       
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'deviceid',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the [DynamoDB Autoscaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html) feature which may not be available on local Dynamodb. DynamoDB autoscaling helps to scale and prevent throttling issues.

> DynamoDB auto scaling uses the AWS Application Auto Scaling service to
>   dynamically adjust provisioned throughput capacity on your behalf, in
>   response to actual traffic patterns. This enables a table or a global
>   secondary index to increase its provisioned read and write capacity to
>   handle sudden increases in traffic, without throttling. When the
>   workload decreases, Application Auto Scaling decreases the throughput
>   so that you don't pay for unused provisioned capacity.

**Best Practice:-**

As a best practice, please ensure that `deviceid` is not sequential. So that the data gets scattered across the partition. This helps to ensure that all the read / writes doesn't use the same partition which is required for the above use case.

[Refer this blog for designing the best partition key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)